# How to use SetWindowDisplayAffinity

Tags: c#, c++

I am beginner . please help me to use this codes in c# win form .

I dont know HWND hWnd . please explain this codes and help me to use this function in C# win form

```
BOOL SetWindowDisplayAffinity(HWND  hWnd,DWORD dwAffinity);
```

Can you wrote sample code for this function in C# win form ? very thanks

Comment: I am beginner and I need to help . I study this

Comment: Let me see what I can do...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You invoke the native win32 API via PInvoke (google it) as follows:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern uint SetWindowDisplayAffinity(IntPtr hwnd, uint dwAffinity);
```

The form has a property called "Handle" that is the native HWND.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern uint SetWindowDisplayAffinity(IntPtr hwnd, uint dwAffinity);



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const uint WDA_NONE = 0;
            const uint WDA_MONITOR = 1;
            SetWindowDisplayAffinity(this.Handle, WDA_MONITOR);
        }
    }
}
```

And now, when I run the program and try to take a screenshot with the print-screen key, this is the actual thing that gets posted to the clipboard:

[image]